# Type of ANOVA that is appropriate to use in this Data

Tags: machine-learning, anova, t-test

We are currently conducting a small study and have very small background in Statistical Analysis. We conducted some experiments and have gathered some data. Can anyone help me in identifying what type of Statistical Treatment we can use for this?

[image: Depth pertains to the setup, second column to the number of trials, third as the constant variable and fourth as the results]

The first column is for the setups, second column for the trials, third for the constant variable and the fourth one is for the results. We were instructed not to use T-Test and use ANOVA instead. Now we are confused whether to use

1. Ordinary One-Way ANOVA
2. One Way ANOVA with Repeated Measures
3. Two-Way ANOVA
4. Two-Way ANOVA with Repeated Measures

I hope some of you can help me with this. I know that this sound dumb but we're really confused (coz of the lack of background).

Comment: Is this just a sample of your data ? If it is the entire data then you are in trouble. If not, then please let us know the sample size.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data has generated among two variables: setups and trials, and for every of their combination (setups*trials) you have just one value; I think you should use **Two-Way ANOVA**.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have one independent variable (depth) (but maybe also actual latitude) and one dependent variable (transmitted latitude) and maybe repeats.  But there are a bunch of issues:

1. Transmitted latitude is constant at each depth, so the repeats are problematic.
2. Transmitted latitude is the same for three of the four depths, so depth is problematic.
3. Depth is, presumably, on a ratio scale, so ANOVA is problematic.
4. Actual latitude is constant, so that is also problematic.
5. The sample size is very small.

Sorry to be negative, but with the data shown, I'm not sure there is any useful analysis. If I had to do something, I would try either a) a multilevel model including the repeats or b) Ignoring the repeats and doing regression with N = 4.